# css3 card flip hover and click conflict

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I am creating card flip effect using css3.

I am flipping card using jQuery and css

**css**

```
    .flipped {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    transform: rotateY( 180deg );
}
```

**jQuery**

```
<script>
$(".card").click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#' + id).toggleClass('flipped');
});
```

### Its working fine but when i have applied hover effect like

```
.card:hover{
    -webkit-transform: rotateY( 10deg );
    -moz-transform: rotateY( 10deg );
    -o-transform: rotateY( 10deg );
    transform: rotateY( 100deg );
}
```

In this case hover effect is working but onclick Flip effect is only working when we move cursor from the card!

Here is the effect

```js
$(".card").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  $('#' + id).toggleClass('flipped');
});
```

```css
/*Card Flip*/

.card-container {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  -moz-perspective: 800px;
  -o-perspective: 800px;
  perspective: 800px;
  float: left;
  margin: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
.card div {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 150px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 140px;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.card .front {
  background: red;
}
.card .back {
  background: blue;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.card:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(20deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(20deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(20deg);
  transform: rotateY(20deg);
}
.flipped:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(20deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(20deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(20deg);
  transform: rotateY(20deg);
}
/*Card Flip*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="card-container">
  <div class="card" id="card1">
    <div class="front">1</div>
    <div class="back">2</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you have the `:hover` for `.flipped` to rotate to 20degY, so I think its doing what is supposed to do, when you're on hover over it.

One thing would be to replace that `.flipped:hover`, and join it with the class `.flipped`, so that it would rotate to 180degY when its on hover, and when it has that class applied to it, if this is the expected behavior.

```js
$(".card").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  $('#' + id).toggleClass('flipped');
});
```

```css
/*Card Flip*/

.card-container {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  -moz-perspective: 800px;
  -o-perspective: 800px;
  perspective: 800px;
  float: left;
  margin: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
.card div {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 150px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 140px;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.card .front {
  background: red;
}
.card .back {
  background: blue;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(20deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(20deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(20deg);
  transform: rotateY(20deg);
}
.flipped, .flipped:hover {/*notice here*/
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="card-container">
  <div class="card" id="card1">
    <div class="front">1</div>
    <div class="back">2</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: @Eirenaios No problem-o, glad to help out! Cheerio!

Answer (score 1):

Flipped card should actually have 200deg, not 20. Here is jsFiddle example with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/zbgnggkp/2/

```
.flipped:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(200deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(200deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(200deg);
    transform: rotateY(200deg);
}
```